# GSAP ScrollTrigger and max-width

Tags: jquery, scrolltrigger

Is it possible to make GSAP ScrollTrigger to transition between `max-width: none` to `max-width: 1500px`? Or is there another way to keep the website margins on big screens? I have a div that I'd like to have fullwidth initially, but then on scroll keep it to the site margins (with max-width of 1500px).

Right now I've the following code, which makes the div flash on scroll:

```
let cases = document.querySelectorAll('#case .content');

for(let i=0; i < cases.length; i++) {
gsap.fromTo("#case .content", {
padding: "0%",  
maxWidth: "none",       
}, {
padding: "5%",
maxWidth: "1500px", 
scrollTrigger:{
    trigger: "#case .content",
    scrub: true,
    pin: false,
    markers: true,
    duration:2.5,  
    ease: "Power3.easeInOut",  
    delay: "0",
    start: "top center",
    end: "top 10%"},
ease: "none"
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `max-width:none;` turns out to be giving jerks in animations. You can try `max-width: unset;` or `max-width: 0;` instead.